# Python Win32, how to save an XLS as a CSV?

Tags: python, excel, csv, win32com

I'm loading up a .xlsx with win32com and would like to save the results as a csv when I'm done.

```
myworkbook.SaveAs('results.csv')
```

gives me an xlsx file with a csv extension. How do I save as an actual CSV?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I *think* that if you add the type after the filename, it should work. (Can't test right now.)

I think the type for CSV (DOS) is 24.

```
myworkbook.SaveAs('results.csv', 24)
```

Comment: I thought the value for `xlCSV` is 6.

Answer (score 4):

Here are the docs for saveAs:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb214129.aspx

```
from win32com.client import constants as c
myWorkBook.SaveAs('results.csv', c.xlCSV)
```

Comment: If the file already exists, then Excel will show a pop-up window.  Is there a way to deal with this, or direct the function to always overwrite?

Comment: You can set `xl.DisplayAlerts = False` beforehand and Excel will just overwrite the file.

Answer (score 3):

You have to specify the type after the filename.

For CSV the following modes are available:

```
xlCSV = 6         # Comma separated value.
xlCSVMac = 22,    # Comma separated value.
xlCSVMSDOS = 24,  # Comma separated value.
xlCSVWindows =23, # Comma separated value.
```

Available file formats can be fond [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.xlfileformat.aspx), the spec of the saveAs method can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.excel.workbook.saveas%28v=VS.80%29.aspx). Even as there is no example for python, the parameters and values should be the same.

Answer (score 1):

I have not used this library but it might be worth giving a shot:

http://pypi.python.org/pypi/ooxml

Comment: I need to load a plugin, so a regular xlsx parsing library is no-go. win32com does what I need, the problem is the SaveAs method docstring is unclear.